# Extra edges in rendered mode

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

The face of the cube is triangulated in rendered mod, while in solid mode it is not:
[image]

[image]

How can i make the face of the cube look on render the same way as in solid mode (without that "extra" edge)?

I managed to get result that is on 3-rd pic using subdiv modifier. Is that the only way, or there is another, maybe, an easier one or more effective? (Besides, I have to save positions of all cube's vertices.)
[image]

Comment: Your 4 vertices are not on the same plane, so instead of being one quad they actually form two triangles. That's not visible in `solid` mode but you would have to use a shadeless material for it to be hidden in cycles (an emit shader should do it)

Comment: Shadeless material is bad for me. Then how can i get rid of that extra edge in terms of modeling, not shading. For exemple, i managed to get result that is on 3-rd pic using subdiv modifier. Is that the only way, or there is another, maybe, an easier one or more effective?

Comment: One way you could do that is to scale them on one axis to force them onto the same plane. So here with the four vertices selected if you type `s` (to scale) then `x` (on the x axis) then `0` (to zero) you should end up with just one "continuous" face.

Comment: Right, it's the way, but i have to save positions of all cube's vertices.

Comment: Okay, then that face couldn't exist in reality as a solid one, but if you switch shading to smooth (in `Object`, top left) it should look the way you want it to, and it's better than subsurfing :)